# How to make android sdk 4.0.3 with android 4.0.4 source code?

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I've downloaded the Android source code 4.0.4 and built the sdk 4.0.4 AOSP successfully.
When I use my custom sdk, the eclipse told me that I have to set minSdkVersion="AOSP" in Manifest.xml, and the tragedy is, my device version is 4.0.3 and can't run apk on it.

What should I do?

I think there're may be two solutions:

1.Build a NONE AOSP SDK and run 4.0.4 sdk on 4.0.3 devices.

2.Check out the source code 4.0.3 and re-make the sdk. (which also may have the "AOSP" problem)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How were you able to build the SDK for 4.0.4?

Comment: I checked out source code from AOSP 2 years ago and build the 4.0.4 SDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in solution 1:

Modify: build/core/version_defaults.mk PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME to：

If this is a final release build, it is simply “REL”.
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME := REL

This mark the built sdk as a release version.

Comment: Check it as an answer, please!

Comment: I have to wait about 4 hours to check my own answer.